# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "zum/zur" und "um zu"?

Tags: standard-german

Ich habe eine wichtige Frage. Obwohl ich viele Male mit vielfältigen ähnlich Fällen gefragt habe, habe ich leider nicht verstanden, wie ich einen Satz mit "zum/zur" beginne. Ich weiß nicht, wenn ich meinen Satz mit "zum/zur" beginne, ist es grammatisch richtig oder falsch.

> Zum Finden einer Wohnung habe ich im Internet gesucht

Answer (score 2):

Diese Frage betrifft nicht die Grammatik (Regeln von Satzbau und Formenbildung) sondern eher die Semantik (Bedeutung) und Pragmatik (wie sagt man etwas in welcher Situation).

Ausgehend von Deinem Beispielsatz *Zum Finden einer Wohnung habe ich im Internet gesucht* drängt sich mir folgender Eindruck auf:

***Um zu finden*** wird vorwiegend verwendet, wenn es um ein konkretes Ziel geht. In deinem Fall: Du suchst ganz konkret eine Wohnung für dich:

> Um eine Wohnung zu finden, habe ich die Angebote im Internet durchsucht.
>
> Um endlich eine Wohnung zu finden, habe ich schon alles mögliche getan.
>
> Ich habe mich an einen Makler gewandt, um endlich eine Wohnung zu finden, aber ich habe kein gutes Gefühl dabei, denn diese Geier beuten einen nach Strich und Faden aus.

***Zum Finden*** wird eher verwendet, wenn das Wohnungssuchen unkonkret (allgemein, abstrakt) gemeint ist:

> Zum Finden einer Wohnung empfiehlt es sich, alle möglichen Informationsquellen zu nutzen.
>
> Zum Finden einer Wohnung braucht man viel Geduld.
>
> Das Finden einer Wohnung ist für manche unmöglich geworden. = Für manche ist es unmöglich geworden, eine Wohnung zu finden.<sup>1</sup>

Du kannst auch sagen *Zum Finden einer Wohnung habe ich  mich an einen Makler gewandt / im Internet gesucht / Zettel an Laternenmasten geklebt*, und jedermann wird dich verstehen, aber es klingt ein bisschen unbeholfen, da du eine konkrete Wohnungssuche meinst, nicht eine abstrakte. In mündlichen Kommunikationssituationen wird das nur wenigen auffallen, in schriftlicher Kommunikation stolpert der Leser dann aber doch drüber.

---

<sup>1</sup> Wichtig: nicht *um zu*! *Um zu* ist für die konkreten Fälle.

Comment: So allgemein, dass es vielleicht nicht gefragt war: *Um zu* beschreibt immer ein Ziel oder einen Zweck. *Zum*/*zur* kann auch ein Ortsangabe sein, wie *ich gehe zum Dorfbrunnen*.

Answer (score -1):

Zum Schaschlick empfehle ich Zaziki. Alles andere ist Quark.

Zum Verständnis nochmal:

Um zu verstehen, wo der Unterschied liegt, beachte dass *Zu dem Finden* völlig unmöglich ist. Ich kann grad nicht sagen, wieso. Es erscheint mir wie eine schlechte Englischübersetzung von *to find*, die ähnlich unidiomatisch zurückübersetzt aber *to finding* oder schlimmeres ergeben würde.